# How save an ID in relationship field - symfony

Tags: symfony

My field in the entity client:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ClientRestrictiveListValidationType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_type_validation")
 */
private $validationType;
```

to save I must do the following:

```
$validationType = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ValidationType::class)->find($idValidationType);
$client->setValidationType($validationType);
```

but when looking for the type of validation, I am doing an extra query.
If I already have the $idValidationType I want to save, I don't want to do an extra query.

The entity  is old and the properties is used for other services, for that I can't change the properties

Comment: Best to just use the object since that is what Doctrine is designed to do.  But if you insist, check out EntityManager::getReference(EntityType,$id).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed